# ASP Core Text Box Array not binding in action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

II have created a dynamic form, allowing users to add rows to a table which contains inputs for entry.

I want to bind the array of fields to a model in the action.

I believe i have followed the correct naming procedure for any additional rows "fieldName[0]"

I created an entry and posted to the action but the binding does not happen

I have checked the Headers of the request and can see the information being posted

here is the form data:

```
CompanyAllId[0]: 0
EmployeeId[0]: 0
Name[0]: Test Name
Position[0]: Manager
MonthlyEarnings[0]: 10000
startDate[0]: 02/04/2018 17:58:00
EmploymentType[0]: Full Time
```

here is my view

```
<form asp-action="SaveEmployee">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" id="employee-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Position
                </th>
                <th>
                    Monthly Earnings
                </th>
                <th>
                    Start Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Employment Type
                </th>

        </thead>
        <tbody class="table-body">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr class="table-row" data-id="0">
                    @Html.Hidden("CompanyAllId[" + i + "]", Model[i].CompanyAllId)
                    @Html.Hidden("EmployeeId[" + i + "]", Model[i].EmployeeId)
                    <td> @Html.TextBox("Name[" + i + "]", Model[i].Name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("Position[" + i + "]", Model[i].Position)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("MonthlyEarnings[" + i + "]", Model[i].MonthlyEarnings)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("startDate[" + i + "]", Model[i].startDate)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("EmploymentType[" + i + "]", Model[i].EmploymentType)</td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="clone-button btn btn-flat btn-primary">Add Row</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveEmployee(List<Models.CompanyViewModels.Employees.Employee> vm)
{

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Show what your are posting to the Action, are using Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe i have followed the correct naming

Nope, you didn't. You have to give the index to the element, not to the properties.
So, if your parameter is named `vm`:

```
@Html.Hidden("vm[" + i + "].CompanyAllId", Model[i].CompanyAllId)
@Html.Hidden("vm[" + i + "].EmployeeId", Model[i].EmployeeId)
<td> @Html.TextBox("vm[" + i + "].Name", Model[i].Name)</td>
<td>@Html.TextBox("vm[" + i + "].Position", Model[i].Position)</td>
<td>@Html.TextBox("vm[" + i + "].MonthlyEarnings", Model[i].MonthlyEarnings)</td>
<td>@Html.TextBox("vm[" + i + "].startDate", Model[i].startDate)</td>
<td>@Html.TextBox("vm[" + i + "].EmploymentType", Model[i].EmploymentType)</td>
```

So, you should end up with something like...

```
vm[0].CompanyAllId: 0
vm[0].EmployeeId: 0
vm[0].Name: Test Name
vm[0].Position: Manager
vm[0].MonthlyEarnings: 10000
vm[0].startDate: 02/04/2018 17:58:00
vm[0].EmploymentType: Full Time
```

Comment: Ive just replaced with your code and swapped "vm" for "model", it binds when viewing. But returning the data does not bind. Is this the right thing to do?

Comment: @PowerMan2015 I don't see how you are adding rows to the table (you didn't post any code). Post that and your model class

Comment: Ive got it working, i didn't realize that the proceeding part of the of the naming needed to match the parameter name in the action. Thanks for you help

Comment: @PowerMan2015 I assumed it could be that, that's why I added "So, if your parameter is named vm" :)